# How to create a dynamic command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to have a command in a variable that runs a program and specifies the output filename for it depending on the number of files exits (to work on a  new file each time).

Here is what I have:

`export MY_COMMAND="myprogram -o ./dir/outfile-0.txt"`

However I would like to make this `outfile` number increases each time `MY_COMMAND` is being executed. You may suppose `myprogram` creates the file soon enough before the next call. So the number can be retrieved from the number of files exists in the directory `./dir/`. I do not have access to change myprogram itself or the use of `MY_COMMAND`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify ... you can't modify `myprogram` and you can't change the way that `MY_COMMAND` is _called_, but you _can_ provide a new definition for MY_COMMAND? I would also assume you aren't limited to `export MY_COMMAND=...` — you could write a shell script as complex as necessary and name it, or invoke it from, MY_COMMAND.

Comment: You are right and the answer works though I did not give more details and is that the command ${MY_COMMAND} is being used with some other arguments that I do not have control on. So with your solution I should pass them to the program via `"$@"` which is good but may cause an issue if the input has double quotations. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of answer to this: 1) create an index file, 2) search for last, then incrase numbre, 3) count files, add +1... And so on... Did you already try something? Please show us what did you already tried!

Comment: I wrote an script that actually finds out the number of files in the directory and then run the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you can't change `myprogram` — its `-o` option will always write to the file given on the command line, and assuming that something *also* out of your control is running `MY_COMMAND` so you can't change the way that `MY_COMMAND` gets called, you still have control of `MY_COMMAND`

For the rest of this answer I'm going to change the name `MY_COMMAND` to `callprog` mostly because it's easier to type.

You can define `callprog` as a variable as in your example `export callprog="myprogram -o ./dir/outfile-0.txt"`, but you could instead write a shell script and name *that* `callprog`, and a shell script can do pretty much anything you want.

So, you have a directory full of `outfile-<num>.txt` files and you want to output to the next non-colliding `outfile-<num+1>.txt`.

Your shell script can get the numbers by listing the files, cutting out only the numbers, sorting them, then take the highest number.

If we have these files in `dir`:

```
outfile-0.txt
outfile-1.txt
outfile-5.txt
outfile-10.txt
```

`ls -1 ./dir/outfile*.txt` produces the list

```
./dir/outfile-0.txt
./dir/outfile-1.txt
./dir/outfile-10.txt
./dir/outfile-5.txt
```

(using `outfile` and `.txt` means this will work even if there are other files not name *outfile*)
Scrape out the number by piping it through the stream editor `sed` … capture the number and keep only that part:

```
ls -1 ./dir/outfile*.txt | sed -e 's:^.*dir/outfile-\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.txt$:\1:'
```

(I'm using colon `:` instead of the standard slash `/` so I don't have to escape the directory separator in `dir/outfile`)

Now you just need to pick the highest number. Sort the numbers and take the top

```
| sort -rn | head -1
```

Sorting with `-n` is numeric, not lexigraphic sorting, `-r` reverses so the highest number will be *first*, not last.

Putting it all together, this will list the files, edit the names keeping *only* the numeric part, sort, and get just the first entry. You want to assign that to a variable to work with it, so it is:

```
high=$(ls -1 ./dir/outfile*.txt | sed -e 's:^.*dir/outfile-\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.txt$:\1:' | sort -rn | head -1)
```

In the shell (I'm using bash) you can do math on that, `$[high + 1]` so if *high* is 10, the expression produces `11`
You would use that as the numeric part of your filename.

The whole shell script then just needs to use that number in the filename. Here it is, with lines broken for better readability:

```
#!/bin/sh

high=$(ls -1 ./dir/outfile*.txt \
       | sed -e 's:^.*dir/outfile-\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.txt$:\1:' \
       | sort -rn | head -1)

echo "myprogram -o ./dir/outfile-$[high + 1].txt"
```

Of course you wouldn't ***echo*** myprogram, you'd just run it.

Comment: `sed` could be written: `..file-\([0-9]\+\)\.tx..` or   `..file-\([1-9][0-9]*\)\.tx..` ;) Correct answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in a bash function under your .bashrc by using wc to get the number of files in the dir and then adding 1 to the result

```
yourfunction () {
dir=/path/to/dir
filenum=$(expr $(ls $dir | wc -w) + 1)
myprogram -o $dir/outfile-${filenum}.txt
}
```

this should get the number of files in $dir and append 1 to that number to get the number you need for the filename. if you place it in your .bashrc or under .bash_aliases and source .bashrc then it should work like any other shell command

Comment: The function is a good idea. `expr` is unnecessary; use `$(( ... + 1))` instead. Parsing the output of `ls` is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting a function for `MY_COMMAND` to run.

```
next_outfile () {
    my_program -o ./dir/outfile-${_next_number}.txt
    ((_next_number ++ ))
}

export -f next_outfile
export MY_COMMAND="next_outfile" _next_number=0
```

This relies on a "private" global variable `_next_number` being initialized to 0 and not otherwise modified.